# sda1 resize issue, no LVM, gparted not working due to partition method

Tags: partitioning, gparted, lvm, clonezilla

My sda1 partition is full.
I'm not using LVM and had setup sda2 as extended partition. 
I've unallocated space which Im not able to extend to sda 1 even after using gparted due to how I had partitioned. [image: <<**gparted screenshot**>>]

is there any way to increase sda1 size?
or 
should I clone it to an external hard drive, resize my sda1 partition by formatting it and changing the partition table and restore the cloned image so i can get my sda1 size increased by having my data and settings intact.

for the 2nd proposed method is there any article which would help me out like using tools such as clonezilla.

Comment: Edit your question and show me a screenshot of `gparted`.

Comment: @heynnema please take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. I reviewed it, and there are a number of problems. The disk is in MBR format (and should be in GPT format if you've got a newer UEFI computer), you've partitioned it into four unnecessary partitions for such a small HDD. You've got an unallocated  93G of space. Seriously, I'd recommend backing up any important data, formatting the disk (prefer GPT), and reinstalling Ubuntu without the four partitions (let Ubuntu decide how to partition). Much better long term result.